# How to perform an action programmatic like action performed of JButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, abstraction

I have a actionSave class which extends AbstractAction.I use it for save button. somewhere else i want to run the same instant of it which was used for the button.
I came to conclusion to use it as below but i do not know what to pass as argument?

```
model.getActionSave().actionPerformed("what should i add here for action event");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the code of the `actionPerformed()` method into another method without argument, and call this method instead:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    save();
}

public void save() {
    ...
}

...

model.getActionSave().save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own `ActionEvent`, it has a public constructor. E.g.

```
model.getActionSave().actionPerformed( 
 new ActionEvent( this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "Save" )
);
```

If you are e.g. testing your UI, you can also opt to perform a click on the button through the API:

```
button.doClick();
```

But in general I prefer the first approach, and avoid the coupling with the UI